# Regex to split emails into an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to come up with a regex to split up email addresses into an array, which has to cover several scenarios:

```
1. a@a.com; b@b.com; c@c.com;
2. a@a.com; b@b.com; c@c.com
3. a@a.com b@b.com c@c.com
```

I have currently managed to come up with this code which only successfully covers case number 2, and misses the last one on case number 1.

```
const regex = /\s?([^\s<>@]+@[^\s<>@]+)(;|$)/g;
const rv = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), match => match[1]);
```

I have been trying several variations to include a space in the end clause `(;|\s|$)` but that just breaks others.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: instead of using regex, would it not be simpler to just `string.split(" ")` and remove the `;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Tulad you can remove the `;` semicolon first and then split on space

```js
const str = "a@a.com; b@b.com; c@c.com;";
const rv = str.replace(/[;]/g, "").split(/\s+/);

console.log(rv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex you could replace/split (or just split if you want to keep the semi-colons).

```js
const string = 'a@a.com; b@b.com; c@c.com;';
const result = string.replaceAll(';', '').split(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the email format as in the pattern that you tried, and there can not be a semicolon, you can exclude matching that as well adding it to the negated character class.

You can exclude the optional `\s?` and omit the capture group from the pattern to get the match only.

```js
[
  "a@a.com; b@b.com; c@c.com;",
  "a@a.com; b@b.com; c@c.com",
  "a@a.com b@b.com c@c.com"
].forEach(str =>
  console.log(
    str.match(/[^\s<>@]+@[^\s<>;@]+/g)
  )
);
```

Comment: `str.match(/[^\s<>@]+@[^\s<>;@]+/g)` would be shorter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes you are right..something with copy and pasting :-)